# userform textbox to function if kept blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a useform which helps me to change the column width and row height of active sheet or all the sheets (based on the selection option in Frame3) from column B or Column C (based on the selection option in Frame2) based on the text entered in the textbox1 and textbox2.
I have attacahed userform for your reference.
[image: Userform]

This code is working fine, however if I only need to change the column width not the row height then when I key in the column width and leave the row height empty then its giving me error on the below mentioned line:
 Selection.Cells.RowHeight = Me.TextBox2.Value

Please let me know how should I modify my code that even if any of the textbox value is left blank (i.e if I only want to change the column width and maintain the row height as-is) then it should not give me error.

Userform Code:

```
Dim exworkb As Workbook
Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
Dim firstrowDB As Long
Dim Z As Integer
Dim ShtNames() As String

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If Me.OptionButton3.Value = True Then
    If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Call rowcolactivesheetb
        Selection.Cells.RowHeight = Me.TextBox2.Value
        Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = Me.TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        For Z = 1 To Sheets.Count
            ShtNames(Z) = Sheets(Z).Name
            If ShtNames(Z) <> "Trans_Letter" And ShtNames(Z) <> "Cover" And ShtNames(Z) <> "Abbreviations" And InStr(ShtNames(Z), "_Index") = 0 Then
                Sheets(Z).Select
                lastrow1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                lastcolumn1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(1, 2), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
                Selection.Cells.RowHeight = Me.TextBox2.Value
                Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = Me.TextBox1.Value
            End If
        Next Z
    End If
End If

If Me.OptionButton4.Value = True Then
    If Me.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Call rowcolactivesheetc
        Selection.Cells.RowHeight = Me.TextBox2.Value
        Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = Me.TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf Me.OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        ReDim ShtNames(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        For Z = 1 To Sheets.Count
            ShtNames(Z) = Sheets(Z).Name
            Sheets(Z).Select
            If ShtNames(Z) <> "Trans_Letter" And ShtNames(Z) <> "Cover" And ShtNames(Z) <> "Abbreviations" And InStr(ShtNames(Z), "_Index") = 0 Then
                lastrow1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                lastcolumn1 = Sheets(Z).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Z).Range(Sheets(Z).Cells(1, 3), Sheets(Z).Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
                Selection.Cells.RowHeight = Me.TextBox2.Value
                Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = Me.TextBox1.Value
            End If
        Next Z
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Module code:

```
Sub rowcolactivesheetb()

Dim exworkb As Workbook
Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
Dim firstrowDB As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub rowcolactivesheetc()

Dim exworkb As Workbook
Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow1 As Long
Dim lastcolumn1 As Long
Dim firstrowDB As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn1 = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lastrow1, lastcolumn1)).Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: add the selection.cells.rowheight inside an if function checking the value of the textbox and if its not vbnullstring then change the row height. you can do the similar thing to the column width also if you prefer

Comment: While @SivaprasathV is right and that would be the preferred way of solving this issue I don't think this is what **you** want. Looking at your recent posting history and how you disregarded all the great propositions you got from so many gifted programmers on this site I'd suggest that you do what most people here will frown upon and simple implement this one line `On Error Resume Next`. Basically, this tells VBA that: if a line of code cannot be execute because it is causing an error then simply skip that line of code and proceed to the next line and go from there. All errors will be ignored

Comment: I have added this line and it helped:

Comment: If Me.TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        Selection.Cells.ColumnWidth = Me.TextBox1.Value
 End If
     If Me.TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
        Selection.Cells.RowHeight = Me.TextBox2.Value
 End If

Comment: @Ralph I really appreciate your suggestions on my last post and this current one as well as it help me a lot

Comment: @SivaparsargV thanks for your advice I will surely incorporate it in my next macro